# How to declare an entity of object type in avro schema

Tags: schema, avro

I have a JSON object, a part of which is as follows:

```
{
  "bounding_box": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -74.026675,
          40.683935
        ],
        [
          -74.026675,
          40.877483
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  }
}
```

Here, **the coordinates are sent as an array of Object**. Now, for this JSON object, I want to create the avro schema (.avsc file), which is, as of now, as follows:

```
{
    "name": "bounding_box",
    "type": {
        "namespace": "my.tweet.stream",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "BoundingBox",
        "fields": [{
                "name": "coordinates",
                "type": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": "object"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "type",
                "type": ["string", "null"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, with the current schema, I am getting the following error:

> Execution generate-id of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.8.1:schema failed: Undefined name: "object"

Could someone help, how can I specify `java.lang.Object` type in avro schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avro is cross-language, and so has no `java.lang.Object` mapping, only `record` types, which can be nested.

You can nest arrays (I only did two levels, but you should be able to have more)

In IDL (`payload.avdl`)

```
@namespace("com.example.mycode.avro")
protocol ExampleProtocol {
  record BoundingBox {
    array<array<double>> coordinates;
   }

  record Payload {
    BoundingBox bounding_box;
    union{null, string} type = null;
  }
}
```

Or in AVSC

generated with `java -jar ~/Applications/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar idl2schemata payload.avdl`

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Payload",
  "namespace" : "com.example.mycode.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "bounding_box",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "BoundingBox",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "coordinates",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : "double"
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "type",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007! I was able to incorporate your approach.